# combining multiple different sql into one

Tags: mysql, sql

```
  cusID | Name | status | Date
---------------------------------
    1   | AA   |    0   | 2013-01-25
    2   | BB   |    1   | 2013-01-23
    3   | CC   |    1   | 2013-01-20



SELECT COUNT(cusID) FROM customer WHERE STATUS=0;
SELECT COUNT(cusID) FROM customer WHERE STATUS=1;
```

Is there a way of combing such two sql and return the results as one. Because want to avoid calling to DB everytime. I tried UNION of two statments, but only showing one result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the shortest possible solution in MySQL.

```
SELECT  SUM(status = 1) totalActive,
        SUM(status = 0) totalInactive
FROM    tableName
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d1bfc/1)

and this is the `CASE` version

```
SELECT  SUM(CASE WHEN status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) totalActive,
        SUM(CASE WHEN status = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) totalInactive
FROM    tableName
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d1bfc/3)

Comment: one thing. is it possible to add another condition like number of customer registered start from that certain date query into that one query (check date column ) etc?